# range of parameter and values in java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

what is the meaning of this sentence:

**Verify that parameter values are in their expected ranges and types. Do not
output debugging error messages and exceptions**

This is in the audit report of my application. the parameter are username and password here for the authentication module

Reasoning:
The application has responded with an error message, indicating an undefined state that may
expose sensitive information.

Comment: It simply means, do not show validation failures by `System.out.println()` or `logger.log()` messages, nor by throwing exceptions. Instead, just show them in the very same HTML form, next or above the input field(s). In [our servlets wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) you can find a basic example of such a validation approach.

Comment: When a user fails to authenticate, the user must NOT know why (non-existing login? wrong password? deactivated user?). Do the checks you need but if anything fails, just print "incorrect login or password". Do not log anything in a file because you risk to log the real password or some info that allows to find it.

Comment: thankyou so much @BalusC. now i am very much clear. also, in try-catch block, whether i should System.out.println() the exception caught in catch or not?

Comment: the question was not code based. so i did not attached any code. i wanted to understand the statement. as the statement was very much unclear to me. but now it is clear to me that the issue was not to print the exceptions and to print "incorrect login and password" only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the authentication fails, you must not provide any information to the user.

You must **NOT**:

- Indicate if the login does not exist (or I can list users with bruteforce).
- Indicate if the password is wrong (or I can guess that the users exist and list them).
- Indicate if the account has been deactivated (let the hacker loose time).
- print the wrong password in logs (because some true user will fail at typing their password and it will let some approaching passwords in the log file)
- print the real password, hashed/crypted or not.
- print anything that is linked with the password.

Always return "incorrect login or password".

**Also note** : many developer store the password in a String which is a **VERY BAD** idea because you don't have access to the String lifecycle. It means that the password still exist somewhere in the JVM. Prefer storing them in char[] and clear it ASAP.

This also mean that you must not print anything that would allow to find the object representing the user in the JVM.

Comment: i am storing request.getParameter("password") in a string but not in session. is this a bad practice?

Comment: Yes. You should not need to get the password back to the JVM. The password should be hashed or crypted in database and you should just do something like `SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE LOGIN = ? AND HASHED_PASSWORD = ?` and put the password in a *PREPARED* query (never use concatened queries). If the query returns something, then the password is good.

Comment: also the auditor made these changes in original reuest.
• Removed parameter 'username'
• Added parameter 'username.' with the following value 'sdfsdf'
• Removed cookie 'JSESSIONID'
• Removed HTTP header 'Cookie=JSESSIONID'

Comment: I also add maximum number of login errors, in HTTP as you can't keep track of the client, it just can clear the cookies, Captcha style solution, to reduce brute-force attacks.

Answer (score 0):

ranges and types: to indicate you should check perhaps string lengths, char seq allowed, dataType(if not done already)
and in general during authentication one should only indicate that the username/pwd might be wrong, not indicating which one. Any other information, might provide insights into your authentication mechanism, how it fails for a particular input type and might be misused.